# Can the mean value theorem of integration be proved without assuming the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was reading a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). During the proof, the mean value theorem for integration is invoked:

$$\int^b_a f(x) = f(c)(b-a)$$

for some $a < c< b$.

However, the proof for the mean value theorem seems to require the fundamental theorem of calculus. I'm hoping that it can be proven without the fundamental theorem, as otherwise, the whole proof becomes circular!

Answer (score 4):

Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. By the extreme value theorem, there are $m,M$ with $m\le f\le M$ on this interval and $m,M\in f([a,b])$. Then: $$m(b-a)\le\int_a^b f\le M(b-a)$$So: $$m\le\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f\le M$$By the intermediate value theorem, applicable since $f$ attains both $m$ and $M$ on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous, there is $x\in[a,b]$, with $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f$.

So, we can prove the integral mean value theorem in a different way to the derivative mean value theorem. Then, after proving FTC, we realise they are essentially the same theorem in different guises. However, the integral one has a nice proof not involving derivatives.